# Angular installation asking for anonymous usage data with the Angular Team

Tags: angular, npm

I'm installing angular for the first time, at this step I was confused whether to accept or not.Here is the message from terminal.

```
 ? Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under
 Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and
 how to change this setting, see http://angular.io/analytics. (y/N)
```

Comment: Did you read the link supplied? If you want to help the Angular dev team improve the product you can opt in.  But, as with all unknown requests, if in doubt click no.

Answer (score 4):

You can help the Angular Team to prioritize features and improvements by permitting the Angular team to send command-line command usage statistics to Google. The Angular Team does not collect usage statistics unless you explicitly opt-in during the Angular CLI installation or upgrade.

Again it's your wish, you can enable/disable later using below command

## Enable all usage analytics.

```
ng analytics on
```

## Disable all usage analytics.

```
ng analytics off
```